# Why is there a syntax error if I don't write 'if' in an END block of AWK?

Tags: awk

I'm learning AWK these days for text processing. But I'm very much confused about AWK syntax. I read on Wikipedia that the syntax follows this format:

```
(conditions) {actions}
```

I assumed I can follow the same syntax in a BEGIN and END block. But I'm getting a syntax error when I run the following script.

```
awk 'BEGIN{}
(1 == 1) {print "hello";}
END{
(1==1) {print "ended"}}' $1
```

However, if I make a little bit of a change inside the END block and add 'if' before the condition, it runs just fine.

```
awk 'BEGIN{}
(1 == 1) {print "hello";}
END{
if (1==1) {print "ended"}}' $1
```

Why is it mandatory to write 'if' in END block while it's not needed in normal blocks?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

AWK programs are a series of rules, and possibly functions. Rules are defined as a [pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Pattern-Overview.html) (`(conditions)` in your format) followed by an [action](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Action-Overview.html); either are optional.

`BEGIN` and `END` are [special patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGIN_002fEND.html).

Thus in

```awk
BEGIN {}
(1 == 1) { print "hello"; }
END { if (1 == 1) { print "ended" } }
```

the patterns are `BEGIN`, `(1 == 1)` (and the parentheses aren’t necessary), and `END`.

Blocks inside braces after a pattern (or without a pattern, to match everything) are [actions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Action-Overview.html). You can’t write patterns as such *inside* a block, each block is governed by the pattern which introduces it. Conditions inside an action must be specified as part of an `if` statement (or other conditional statement, `while` etc.).

The actions above are `{}` (the empty action), `{ print "hello"; }`, and `{ if (1 == 1) { print "ended" } }`.

A block consisting of `{ (1 == 1) { print "ended" } }` results in a syntax error because `(1 == 1)` is a statement here, and must be separated from the following statement in some way; `{ 1 == 1; { print "ended" } }` would be valid, but wouldn’t have the effect you want — `1 == 1` will be evaluated, then separately, `{ print "ended" }`.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting (english) [Wikipedia - Structure of AWK programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Structure_of_AWK_programs)

> An AWK program is a series of pattern action pairs, written as:
>
> ```
> condition { action }
> condition { action }
> ...
> ```
>
> where condition is typically an expression and action is a series of commands.

What the article fails to mention is, the condition or pattern is optional.
This means in your case `(1 == 1)` is not needed, because this is always true.

---

Rewriting the snippet yields

```
BEGIN {}
{ print "hello"; }
END { print "ended"; }
```

And having an empty action, you can skip the line altogether

```
{ print "hello"; }
END { print "ended"; }
```

---

Also note that in the example

```
END {(1 == 1) { print "ended"; }}
```

The pattern/condition is `END` and not `(1 == 1)`. `1 == 1` is inside the action, and so is part of the action. This is also the reason, why there's an error.

Comment: Actually I was just trying to learn this conditional statement syntax. So instead of writing some effective conditions like $1 >5, I was just putting (1 == 1) and (1 != 1 ) for simulating true and false condition . My whole thought process was if the syntax works fine, I can simple replace this 1 == 1 with some useful conditions like $1  == 22 or anything else which is required for a given problem. I was unclear why the exact same statement didnt work in END block. As explained by your answer ( and @Stephen kitt's), I got to know END is actually a special pattern.